# I'm having an error while trying to install polynom package

Tags: packages, installing, polynom

First, I use TeXstudio and I have MikTeX 2.9.

I tried to make TeXstudio automatically install it but it gives me an error saying it cannot find `polynom.sty`. At this point I go around the internet trying to find a solution and I find it. In a few words, I have to install the package manually by first downloading the files from CTAN, which I did, and then open the two files .dtx and .ins with my editor and compile them, which I did but that gives me this error:

```
Could not start Default Compiler:PdfLaTeX:  
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "polynom".tex.
```

I also ended up with a texput.txt saying this:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.4.15)  28 MAR 2017 15:30  
entering extended mode  
**polynom.tex

! Emergency stop.  
<*> polynom.tex

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  
2 strings out of 493634  
17 string characters out of 3141299  
52604 words of memory out of 3000000  
3491 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000  
3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000  
1025 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191  
0i,0n,0p,1b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I don't really understand what's the problem. Can someone help me?

Comment: Refer to this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359851/117534 See if it helps. Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Hello, it could be helpful to have a MWE.

Comment: @ilFuria Sorry, I'm kind of new to LaTeX. What is a MWE?

Comment: @Alex a Minimal Working Example [I would refer to this post and its answers](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe)

Comment: @ilFuria I don't think an MWE is useful in this case. Alex is simply asking how one should go about installing packages? Alex, have you taken a look at my posted link? MikTeX as a package manager that allows you to install packages directly.

Comment: There is no need to install the package manually. Use the miktex package manager to install polynom. It is doesn't show the package use repositories-> synchronize to update the package list.

Comment: @Troy Yes, I just did what the link said and it worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: And thank you for the others too for the fast response. I'll check that MWE anyway, @ilFuria