# Windows 7, the package acmart could not be installed

Tags: texstudio, acm, acmart

I'm using the ACM template [here](http://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template). I use the `sample-sigconf.tex`. When I open it and  try to compile it, the Tex Studio reports the following error:

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "sample-sigconf".tex

Unfortunately, the package acmart could not be installed.Please check the log file: C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log

Process exited with error(s)
```

Every time I tried to compile, there is a pop up window titled `Package Installation`, saying `acmart` is missing and whether you want to install it. I always choose `yes` but it always reports `cannot install` like above.

What's wrong with my installation?

The `log` information is as follows:

```
2017-07-10 17:36:21,388+0800 INFO  pdflatex - installing package acmart triggered by tex\latex\acmart\acmart.cls
2017-07-10 17:36:23,589+0800 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2017-07-10 17:36:23,589+0800 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Users\fengchao.pfc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9"
2017-07-10 17:36:23,589+0800 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository: http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2017-07-10 17:36:23,590+0800 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: visiting repository http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2017-07-10 17:36:23,590+0800 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: repository type: remote package repository
2017-07-10 17:36:23,590+0800 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: loading lightweight database...
2017-07-10 17:36:23,592+0800 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: downloading http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-07-10 17:36:45,698+0800 FATAL pdflatex - Couldn't connect to server
```

This is not the entire `log` file. I just think these are the related messages.

Comment: what does it say in C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log ?

Comment: Have you tried installing it from the package manager? Follow the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359851/117534)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find it is pretty simply. When I download the ACM template, there is a file called `acmart.ins`. Just `cd` to that directory and and open the command line and run:

```
tex acmart.ins
```

Then the `acmart.cls` is created.
After that, there may be other packages waiting to install. Just try to compile the `.tex` file and follow the instructions in the pop-up messages.